# multiple textbox add with criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sir i have 10 text boxes. 1st two take values from user and display the multiplication result on 3rd text box when it clicked. 4th and 5th textboxes also take values and display the multiplication result in 6th text box when it clicked. like same as above 7th and 8th textbox will work accordingly and 9th textbox will display the multiplication result when it clicked. 10th textbox takes the values from 3rd 6th and 9th textbox and add them.

I can do the multiplication and display the total sum in 10th textbox. Now 6th and 9th textbox may or may not exist then the code is not running in html and javascript.

Please help me.....i am attached the code...

My code

```
<html>
<script >
function getext3(){
txt1 = document.getElementById("text1").value;
txt2 = document.getElementById("text2").value;
document.getElementById("text3").value = parseInt(txt1)*parseInt(txt2);

} 

function getext6(){
txt1 = document.getElementById("text4").value;
txt2 = document.getElementById("text5").value;
document.getElementById("text6").value = parseInt(txt1)*parseInt(txt2);

} 

function getext9(){
txt1 = document.getElementById("text7").value;
txt2 = document.getElementById("text8").value;
document.getElementById("text9").value = parseInt(txt1)*parseInt(txt2);

} 


function getext10(){
if(document.getElementById("text3").value != null && document.getElementById("text6").value == null && document.getElementById("text9").value == null) 
{
txt1 = document.getElementById("text3").value;
document.getElementById("text10").value = txt1; 
}
else if (document.getElementById("text3").value != null && document.getElementById("text6").value != null && document.getElementById("text9").value == null)
{
txt1 = document.getElementById("text3").value;
txt2 = document.getElementById("text6").value;
txt4 = parseInt(txt1)+parseInt(txt2);
document.getElementById("text10").value = txt4; 
}
else(document.getElementById("text3").value != null && document.getElementById("text6").value != null && document.getElementById("text9").value != null)
{
txt1 = document.getElementById("text3").value;
txt2 = document.getElementById("text6").value;
txt3 = document.getElementById("text9").value;
txt4 = parseInt(txt1)+parseInt(txt2)+parseInt(txt3);
document.getElementById("text10").value = txt4; 
}
} 
</script>

Text1 : <input type="text"value="0" id="text1" value=""> <br/>
Text2 : <input type="text" value="0"id="text2" value=""> <br/>
Text3 : <input type="text"value="0"id="text3" value="0" onclick="getext3()"> <br/>


Text4 : <input type="text"value="0"id="text4" value=""> <br/>
Text5 : <input type="text" value="0"id="text5" value=""> <br/>
<!--Text6 : <input type="text" id="text6" value="0" onclick="getext6()"> <br/>-->


Text7 : <input type="text"value="0"id="text7" value=""> <br/>
Text8 : <input type="text" value="0"id="text8" value=""> <br/>
<!--Text9 : <input type="text" id="text9" value="0" onclick="getext9()"> <br/>-->

Text10 : <input type="text" id="text10" value="" onclick="getext10()"> <br/>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code

```
<html>
<script >
function getext3(){
txt1 = document.getElementById("text1").value;
txt2 = document.getElementById("text2").value;
document.getElementById("text3").value = parseInt(txt1)*parseInt(txt2);

} 

function getext6(){
txt1 = document.getElementById("text4").value;
txt2 = document.getElementById("text5").value;
document.getElementById("text6").value = parseInt(txt1)*parseInt(txt2);

} 

function getext9(){
txt1 = document.getElementById("text7").value;
txt2 = document.getElementById("text8").value;
document.getElementById("text9").value = parseInt(txt1)*parseInt(txt2);

} 


function getext10(){
     if(document.getElementById("text6").value==null){
    getext6();
    getext9();
    }

    if(document.getElementById("text4").value ==undefined)
   txt1 = document.getElementById("text4").value;
txt2 = document.getElementById("text5").value;
document.getElementById("text6").value = parseInt(txt1)*parseInt(txt2);
    txt1 = document.getElementById("text7").value;
txt2 = document.getElementById("text8").value;
document.getElementById("text9").value = parseInt(txt1)*parseInt(txt2);

if(document.getElementById("text3").value != null && document.getElementById("text6").value == null && document.getElementById("text9").value == null) 
{
txt1 = document.getElementById("text3").value;
document.getElementById("text10").value = txt1; 
}
else if (document.getElementById("text3").value != null && document.getElementById("text6").value != null && document.getElementById("text9").value == null)
{
txt1 = document.getElementById("text3").value;
txt2 = document.getElementById("text6").value;
txt4 = parseInt(txt1)+parseInt(txt2);
document.getElementById("text10").value = txt4; 
}
else(document.getElementById("text3").value != null && document.getElementById("text6").value != null && document.getElementById("text9").value != null)
{
txt1 = document.getElementById("text3").value;
txt2 = document.getElementById("text6").value;
txt3 = document.getElementById("text9").value;
txt4 = parseInt(txt1)+parseInt(txt2)+parseInt(txt3);
document.getElementById("text10").value = txt4; 
}
} 
</script>

Text1 : <input type="text"value="0" id="text1" value=""> <br/>
Text2 : <input type="text" value="0"id="text2" value=""> <br/>
Text3 : <input type="text"value="0"id="text3" value="0" onclick="getext3()"> <br/>


Text4 : <input type="text"value="0"id="text4" value=""> <br/>
Text5 : <input type="text" value="0"id="text5" value=""> <br/>
<!--Text6 : <input type="text" id="text6" value="0" onclick="getext6()"> <br/>-->


Text7 : <input type="text"value="0"id="text7" value=""> <br/>
Text8 : <input type="text" value="0"id="text8" value=""> <br/>
<!--Text9 : <input type="text" id="text9" value="0" onclick="getext9()"> <br/>-->

Text10 : <input type="text" id="text10" value="" onclick="getext10()"> <br/>
</html>
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/L0LszkLo/)

Comment: sir it cant be hide....actually in my project it will come dynamically...so some time it will appear and some time it will not...but cant hide...plz help me with other solution.

Answer (score 0):

`Never define multiple method from same functionality` ,

Define only two methods ,one for `multiplication` and other for `sum`.

EG:-

```
function multiply(element,id1, id2) {
    txt1 = document.getElementById(id1);
    txt2 = document.getElementById(id2);
        element.value =(txt1 ? parseInt(txt1.value) : 1) * (txt2 ? parseInt(txt2.value) : 1);
}

function sum(element,id1, id2, id3) {
    txt1 = document.getElementById(id1);
    txt2 = document.getElementById(id2);
    txt3 = document.getElementById(id3);
    element.value =(txt1 ? parseInt(txt1.value) : 0) + (txt2 ? parseInt(txt2.value) : 0)+ (txt3 ? parseInt(txt3.value) : 0);
}
```

And call them like-

```
onclick="multiply(this,'id_of_element_1','id_of_element_2')"
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/57xzcvsj/)